# One form to another without losing the values to previous entered values in form 1 c#

Tags: c#, user-interface

How do I go back to form 1 without losing the entered values from the user?

I tried:

```
  Form1 fm1 = new Form1();
  fm1.Show();
  this.Hide();
```

but I eraeses the values

Comment: When you do `new Form1()` you are creating a new form, not going back to the original one. To go back you need to either (1) pass a reference to the original `Form1` when you create the new one or (2) from the original form attach to the new form's closing event and show yourself when the new form closes.

Comment: Assuming Form2 is the second form, do you need to go back to it again without losing the values that were there?  In other words, do you need to go back and forth between Form1 and Form2 without losing their values? Do you need to extend this to more than just two forms like a wizard that moves back and forth through screens? Or can you lose the values in Form2 every time, and only need Form1 to retain its values? [ShowDialog()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) may be a possible solution.  Describe your setup better.

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample app to show how you can get a two forms to interact with each other in the way I think you're looking for.

The result looks like this:

[image: Sample App]

- In my app `Form1` has a button to create and show `Form2`. Each time it does that it records the count of how many times it has opened the form.
- When you close any of the opened `Form2` forms it also records how many are closed.
- `Form2` has a text box that raises an event so that `Form1` can display that text.
- And I've passed through the `Form2` open count so that each `Form2` can display the count in its header.

`Form1`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.labelOpenForm2Count.Text = "";
        this.labelCloseForm2Count.Text = "";
        this.labelEnteredText.Text = "";
    }

    private int _openForm2Count = 0;
    private int _closeForm2Count = 0;
    private void buttonOpenForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _openForm2Count += 1;
        var form2 = new Form2(_openForm2Count);
        form2.FormClosed += Form2_FormClosed;
        form2.EnteredTextChanged += Form2_EnteredTextChanged;
        this.labelOpenForm2Count.Text = _openForm2Count.ToString();
        form2.Show();
    }

    private void Form2_EnteredTextChanged(object sender, string enteredText)
    {
        this.labelEnteredText.Text = enteredText;
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is Form2 form2)
        {
            form2.FormClosed -= Form2_FormClosed;
            _closeForm2Count += 1;
            this.labelCloseForm2Count.Text = _closeForm2Count.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

`Form2`:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form2(int count) : this()
    {
        this.Text = count.ToString();
    }

    private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    public event EventHandler<string> EnteredTextChanged;
    private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.EnteredTextChanged?.Invoke(this, textBox.Text);
    }
}
```

And the code in the designer so that you can copy, paste, and run my code.

`Form1`:

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    ///  Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    ///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    ///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.buttonOpenForm2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.labelOpenForm2Count = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.labelCloseForm2Count = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.labelEnteredText = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // buttonOpenForm2
        // 
        this.buttonOpenForm2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
        this.buttonOpenForm2.Name = "buttonOpenForm2";
        this.buttonOpenForm2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(116, 23);
        this.buttonOpenForm2.TabIndex = 0;
        this.buttonOpenForm2.Text = "Open Form2";
        this.buttonOpenForm2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.buttonOpenForm2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonOpenForm2_Click);
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 43);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 23);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.label1.Text = "Opened Form1:";
        this.label1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 62);
        this.label2.Name = "label2";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 23);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 2;
        this.label2.Text = "Closed Form2:";
        this.label2.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        // 
        // labelOpenForm2Count
        // 
        this.labelOpenForm2Count.AutoSize = true;
        this.labelOpenForm2Count.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(119, 47);
        this.labelOpenForm2Count.Name = "labelOpenForm2Count";
        this.labelOpenForm2Count.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 15);
        this.labelOpenForm2Count.TabIndex = 3;
        this.labelOpenForm2Count.Text = "label3";
        this.labelOpenForm2Count.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        // 
        // labelCloseForm2Count
        // 
        this.labelCloseForm2Count.AutoSize = true;
        this.labelCloseForm2Count.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(119, 66);
        this.labelCloseForm2Count.Name = "labelCloseForm2Count";
        this.labelCloseForm2Count.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 15);
        this.labelCloseForm2Count.TabIndex = 4;
        this.labelCloseForm2Count.Text = "label4";
        this.labelCloseForm2Count.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        // 
        // label3
        // 
        this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 96);
        this.label3.Name = "label3";
        this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 23);
        this.label3.TabIndex = 5;
        this.label3.Text = "Entered Text:";
        this.label3.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        // 
        // labelEnteredText
        // 
        this.labelEnteredText.AutoSize = true;
        this.labelEnteredText.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(119, 100);
        this.labelEnteredText.Name = "labelEnteredText";
        this.labelEnteredText.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 15);
        this.labelEnteredText.TabIndex = 6;
        this.labelEnteredText.Text = "label4";
        this.labelEnteredText.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(297, 135);
        this.Controls.Add(this.labelEnteredText);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
        this.Controls.Add(this.labelCloseForm2Count);
        this.Controls.Add(this.labelOpenForm2Count);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.buttonOpenForm2);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonOpenForm2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelOpenForm2Count;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelCloseForm2Count;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelEnteredText;
}
```

`Form2`:

```
partial class Form2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.buttonClose = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.textBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // buttonClose
        // 
        this.buttonClose.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(167, 61);
        this.buttonClose.Name = "buttonClose";
        this.buttonClose.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.buttonClose.TabIndex = 0;
        this.buttonClose.Text = "Close";
        this.buttonClose.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.buttonClose.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.buttonClose_Click);
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(61, 15);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.label1.Text = "Enter Text:";
        // 
        // textBox
        // 
        this.textBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 32);
        this.textBox.Name = "textBox";
        this.textBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(229, 23);
        this.textBox.TabIndex = 2;
        this.textBox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox_TextChanged);
        // 
        // Form2
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(7F, 15F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(254, 94);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.buttonClose);
        this.Name = "Form2";
        this.Text = "Form2";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button buttonClose;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox;
}
```

If you need any further explanation of any part of the code, just ask in the comments below.

Answer (score -1):

This is what i did in my code with multiple forms:

```cs
public Form2 form2;
public Form3 form3;
public Form4 form4;
private Form activeForm = null;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  form2 = new Form2();
  form3 = new Form3();
  form4 = new Form4();
}

private void openForm(Form childForm) {
  if (activeForm != null) {
    activeForm.Visible = false;
    activeForm = null;
  }
  activeForm = childForm;
  childForm.TopLevel = false;
  childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
  childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
  childForm.Refresh();
  // Container Panel is my parent panel
  containerPanel.Controls.Add(childForm);
  containerPanel.Tag = childForm;
  containerPanel.Refresh();
  childForm.BringToFront();
  childForm.Show();
  childForm.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Slow down, upvoting is to indicate a good answer. Your answer is mostly code with little explanation. The OP is clearly still a learner. I think you need to provide clear guidance to what your code is doing.

Comment: Further, there is nothing in your answer that actually answers the OP's question. The OP is dealing with two forms. You've weirdly created three forms, done nothing with them, and that introduced an `openForm` method that isn't called from anywhere and it seems to be trying to attach a form as if it were a control AND it's trying to show the form. This is a bad example of what to do.

Answer (score -1):

In your application, create a c# class and make it static.
declare static variable there.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Class1
    {
        public static string static_variable = null;
    }
}
```

Then you can access this variable in both forms.

Class1.static_variable = "AAA";

if you dont understand please let me know.
you can pass values using delegates too,but this way is easy than that.